# How can I open the Android Settings, and then Applications settings

Tags: android

I know how to open the Android App Settings using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

It opens the Applications Settings, but the selected tab is "**Downloaded**". Can I tell it to display by default the "**All**" tab?

Comment: There is no documented way to do this, in part because there is not necessarily an "All" tab.

Comment: oh ok. and the "running" or other tabs?